# getting location TypeError: _this.map.addEventListener is not a function in ionic

Tags: google-maps, ionic3

Am trying to get the coordinates of location when drag the marker in map.  For that i'm using **addEventListener** and also tried ***this.map.one()*** , ***this.map.on()*** methods too, to get the latitude and longitude. At the time following same type error are occurred for each.

> Error getting location TypeError: _this.map.addEventListener is not a function

Here My code

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {

      console.log('latitude',resp.coords.latitude);
      console.log('longitude',resp.coords.longitude);

      let pos = {
        lat: resp.coords.latitude,
        lng: resp.coords.longitude
      };
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: resp.coords.latitude, lng: resp.coords.longitude },
        zoom: 15
      });

      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: this.map,
        draggable:true,
        title: 'I am here!',
      });

      console.log(pos);

      this.markers.push(marker);
      this.map.setCenter(pos);

      this.map.addEventListener(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_DRAG_END).subscribe(() => {
        this.map.getCameraPosition().then((cameraPosition) => {
          this.temp = JSON.stringify(cameraPosition.target);
          this.temp2 = JSON.parse(this.temp);
          this.currentLatitude = this.temp2.lat;
          this.currentLongitude = this.temp2.lng;
          let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.currentLatitude, this.currentLongitude);
          let request = { latLng: latlng };
          geocoder.geocode(request, (results, status) => {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if (results[0] != null) {
                let address = results[0].formatted_address;
                this.locationObject = address;
              } else { alert("No address available"); }
            }
          });
        });
      });



    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
```

I don't know where i did mistake, Please give me some suggestions.
 Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me too had been struggled for 1 week with this phase, finally I tried to call every method separately and that sounds good. You can try this method.

The following is for initiate the map,

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((response) => {
    let position = {
        lat: response.coords.latitude,
        lng: response.coords.longitude
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: response.coords.latitude, lng: response.coords.longitude },
        zoom: 15
    });
    this.addMarker();
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error getting location', error);
});
```

Next, call the method for marker,

```
addMarker(){
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: this.map,
        draggable: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: this.map.getCenter()
    });
    let content = "<h4>Whatever you want to display!</h4>";   
    this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);
}
```

Next, catch latitude and longitude

```
addInfoWindow(marker, content)
{
    let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: content
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
        infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(){
        this.markerlatlong = marker.getPosition();
        console.log("latitude  => "+marker.getPosition().lat());
        console.log("longitude => "+marker.getPosition().lng());
    });
}
```